# Build PCB with 19 Pin PCB Headers

Tags: pcb, connector

Some time ago, I had a small problem with my mainboard where I was able to come up with a very "special" adapter solution involving like 4 adapters to get everything working.

It looks ugly, takes up a lot of space in my computer, and recently I noticed that somewhere there seems to be a loose connection somewhere in this wiring. In theory I could buy some electronic parts, some wires and solder everything up on my own, but in practice I don't trust my soldering skills and don't really have good soldering equipment.

So my idea was to design a PCB as a side-project and get it manufactured somewhere to fix my problem. However being new to all of this (coming from software engineering) I don't know how to get all of the required parts for this project. I can find them in several online shops for DIY projects, but not on the websites that are used by the first PCB designer tools you can find on Google.

Basically I need two connectors on this PCB:
[image: Male Connector]
[image: Female Connector]

I was able to find the "IDC 19 Pin Male connector" (what it seems to be called) on the LCSC site, but was unable to find the corresponding female connector. Is there any crucial information I'm missing? All I want to do is to order a custom PCB using those two connectors, without any soldering on my own. How would I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction. Have a great day.

Comment: Only one of the connectors above can be mounted on a PCB. The other is an IDC connector meant to be installed on cable, not mounted on PCB. Does that answer your question why you can't find such a connector?

Comment: @jsotola
> that is not a USB anything -- I edited it out.

Comment: @Justme well kind of. I have seen it being soldered to a PCB though: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71lgxEu1wHL._AC_SY450_.jpg Could it be the case that this connector was simply being used the wrong way, and if so what's the alternative? Obviously people are manufacturing this

Answer (score 0):

1. Download free [kicad software (PCB design)](https://www.kicad.org/)
2. Add 19 pin connector holes (thru hole design) to PCB
3. upload PCB file to [oshpark - PCB creator](https://oshpark.com/).
4. order finalized PCB
5. when you receive them solder on your connectors.

You can test variations of your PCB by uploading and seeing result many times before ordering.

Here's a kicad snapshot which shows THT (thru hole connector)

[image: 19pin connector]

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about what's the process of making and ordering a PCB and soldering yourself. The question is about ordering a fully built PCB so no soldering is needed, but stuck because can't find one of the two connectors for PCB mounting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say so, but, reading between the lines, I think you are looking for a board-to-board connector. Well, the connector you picked is a ["Bump" connector](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=bump_conn&f=bump_conn_2p54)  (my site), which is a wire-to-board connector, not a board-to-board connector.

Either I misread your mind, and you are not looking for a PCB-mounted female header. Or, you are looking at the wrong type of connector to solve your problem.

If the latter, please consider mezzanine [board-to-board connectors](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=board_to_board_conn). For example, the [JST XH + JQ](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=board_to_board_conn&o=pin_sckt_b2b_conn&f=pin_sckt_b2b_conn_2p5&s=XH%20%2B%20JQ), which is most similar to the Bump connectors. https://www.jst.co.uk/productSeries.php?pid=60

[image]

Consider also these: https://www.digikey.se/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/HIF6A-20DA-1-27DSA-71/H123956-ND/3978266. They are smaller Bump connectors (1.27 mm pitch instead of 2.54 mm) but they do include a PCB female header.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try to give some context to clarify what I want. Basically for USB 3.0 internal headers 18 of the 19 pins are "pairs" i.e. they do the same thing, but for 2 usb ports in total. My goal is to put those 8 pins into a dedicated 19 pin connector each, so I can connect 2 cables (which only use half of the pins) to the single connector on the mainboard of my PC. Does that help?

Comment: To be honest I don't see the problem here, probably due to my lack of experience regarding this topic. In my head it's simple: Get those 2 pieces in the images I posted, setup wiring, order it, done. Why does the wiring matter at all? Like the question wouldn't be asked differently if I told you I connected all the wrong pins together no?